# Can I use IIF in th update query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access query which I am trying to convert to SQL but getting Msg 102...
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'r'.

can I know what's wrong in this ?

```
UPDATE r 
SET r.Estimate_date_collected = (IIf([LAB].[nationality]='MD',
                                    DateAdd("m",-1,[lab].[Date Received]),
                                    DateAdd("m",-2,[lab].[Date Received])))
From temp as r INNER JOIN temp1 as l
ON r.[ID #] = l.[ID #]
WHERE ((((r.Estimate_date_collected) Is Null)) AND ((r.[Date Coll't]) Is Null))) ;
```

Comment: The Msg 102 error that you are referencing is a SQL Server error.  I assume that temp and/or temp1 are linked tables or queries that reference linked tables in SQL Server.  If you have access to SQL Server Profiler, I would suggest that you run a trace to see what T-SQL MS Access is generating to actually run that query.

Comment: Also, you are referencing fields from a table/query aliased as `Lab` but there is no such table or query included in your `FROM` clause.